# Image transport issue in rviz groovy beta 1

Tags: ros, rviz, image-transport, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having problems running rviz in ros groovy beta 1 (the one that comes with the groovy binaries when you do apt-get install ros-groovy-visualization). It says it is unable to subscribe to the left/right camera topic. I'm able to add the plugin in the UI, but when I try to change the topic to one of the cameras, this is what I get:

Error subscribing: Unable to load plugin for transport 'raw', error string:
MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create class of type image_transport::RawSubscriber

I've tried this in a clean install of ubuntu 12.04 and it did not work. I've also downloaded fuerte and the visualization stack on the same machine and tested rviz, and it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? I'm using the DRC sim and gazebo 1.3 with fuerte. Is it possible this is some sort of incompatibility issue between messages from fuerte and groovy?

I installed every groovy package available (apt-get install ros-groovy-*) just in case, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. There is a "fix" to this error that has been committed in github, but it's really just so it shows a msgbox with the error, so it doesn't really solve it.

Thanks,
Felipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50091/image-transport-issue-in-rviz-groovy-beta-1/) by [Felipe Bacim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3757/felipe-bacim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-12-10**:
Just tested with Beta2, doesn't work there either (Spawning a PR2 in gazebo and trying to visualize images in rviz).

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2012-12-10**:
Could you tell me what version of ros-groovy-class-loader you have from .debs?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-12-10**:
Just checked again, issue seems to be related to something in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH that screws up the plugin finding. Investigating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error was related to having additional directories in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, among them '/opt/ros/fuerte/lib', which is clearly is not optimal :) With a completely clean groovy install, transmitting images work (and with a proper workspace setup, transmitting images from a fuerte source to a groovy rviz also works).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-20**:\

> and with a proper workspace setup, transmitting images from a fuerte source to a groovy rviz also works

How would you suggest properly setting up both these distros so that the library from Fuerte doesn't interfere?